# Increment a number with leading zero

Tags: powershell

```
#Job name to find. Jobname is in the format of SQL01, SQL02, SQL03...
$Jobtofind = Read-host -Prompt "Provide the job name to find"

#Count should have the format '01', '02', '03'...
$Count = '{0:d2}' -f 1

# Match the Jobname
if ("SQL$Count" -match $Jobtofind) {"YES job found"} else { "Increment the count and match the jobname"}
```

1. Unable to increment the number leading zero
2. After incrementing how to go to if loop to find a match?

Comment: Where do you get `SQL$Count`'s value?

Comment: Maybe $Count = '{0:d2}' -f $JobToFind ??

Answer (score 2):

What we still don't know is your overall goal with this piece of code. That context will help tailor a proper solution. However, we can address the questions in the post.

1. How to increment in a two digit number format? Note that you will need additional logic to control how many times `$count` increments.

   ```
   $count = 1 # Starting number
   '{0:d2}' -f $count++ # Increments $count after outputting its current two digit value
   ```
2. How to keep incrementing until a match is found?

   ```
   $JobToFind = 'SQL07'
   $count = 1
   # $NoMatch will be $true until a match is found
   # We don't want to check 3 digit numbers
   while (($NoMatch = "SQL$('{0:d2}' -f $count)" -ne $JobToFind) -and $count -lt 100) {
       "Incrementing count to find job"
       $count++
   }
   if ($NoMatch) {
       "No job found"
   }
   else {
       "YES job found"
   }
   ```

---

If you want to just see if a job name matches a particular format, you may use the `-match` operator with a regex pattern or the `-like` operator with a wildcard pattern.

```
$JobToFind = 'SQL23'
# Not case-sensitive. Use -cmatch for case-sensitivity
# \d matches a digit
# ^ is beginning of string. $ is end of string
# returns True if there is a match and False otherwise
$JobToFind -match '^SQL\d\d$'

# Returns True on match and False otherwise
# Use -clike for case-sensitivity
$JobToFind -like 'SQL[0-9][0-9]'
```

If you want a two digit number match but never match `00`, you can either use multiple conditions or an alternation (`|`) in your regex pattern. Of course, you are free to mix and match `-like` and `-match` operators.

```
# Match two digit numbers if not 00
# (?!0) matches when next character is not 0
$JobToFind -match '^SQL(0(?!0)|[1-9])\d$'

# Using multiple conditions and regex
$JobToFind -match '^SQL\d\d$' -and $JobToFind -notmatch '00$'

# Using wildcard and multiple conditions
$JobToFind -like 'SQL[0-9][0-9]' -and $JobToFind -notlike '*00'
```

Comment: I love the RegEx explanation!